# How do I clone an SVG?

Tags: html, css

How do I clone this SVG for 5 times without repeating myself? I don't want this ex: `<img src="SVG"/>` to be repeated in my HTML file like 5 or more times. For example I have an SVG with one star but I want to have 5 stars, all the same, in the same SVG . How do I apply this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use "use"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

You can define it once and then reuse it.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
    <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue"/>
    <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue"/>
    <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your tech stack. For example, if you use React and JSX, you can use js loops and render the same element three times.

Also, there're many template engines like

- https://handlebarsjs.com
- https://mustache.github.io
- https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks
- https://github.com/pugjs/pug

So, it's impossible to do with plain HTML/CSS (if I understood you correctly), but you can use the template engine of your choice to achieve that.

Comment: oh, I understand, I appreciate your help